# Try await swit errors thrown from here are not handled - Swift 5.5,*

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to initialize a variable (in a ViewModel) with some value from the db using async await introduced in swift 5.5, but I'm getting the error:

```
Errors thrown from here are not handled
```

This is the code:

```
@Published var userWallets: [Wallet]

init() async {
    // Get current User
    let user = await NetworkController().getUser()
    
    // Publish all wallets
    userWallets = try await getUserWallets(user: user)
}
```

I have tried to wrap it around a `Task` but then it says: `'self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized`

How to I initialize that value correctly?

Comment: While it's perfectly fine to make an init async and throwing, it defeats the purpose of your ViewModel. When you start showing your View, it should "know" when the view model is loading data, so it can show an activity indicator. When your data eventually arrives, your ViewModel updates its userWallets accordingly, which the  View can then render. So, let your view state have a "loading" mode and an "idle" mode. So, your init is actually _not_ async - just the getUserWallets function is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, `getUserWallets(user:)` can throw. You therefore have two choices on how to deal with this:

1. Make the `init` throw as well:

```swift
init() async throws {
    // ...
    
    userWallets = try await getUserWallets(user: user)
}
```

This means that you have to deal with the error when initializing your struct or class.

2. Handle the error in some way:

```swift
init() async {
    // ...
    
    do {
        userWallets = try await getUserWallets(user: user)
    } catch {
        // handle the error here in some way
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried doing the do catch, but not the first option. Both ways throw the following error: `Variable 'self.userWallets' used before being initialized` any idea? I would like to initialize it here not in the actual `@Publish`

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is because `userWallets` is only assigned after the object might already be initialized, but I'm not 100% on this. I see two solutions to this: Initialize `userWallets` to an empty array and/or decouple the code that fetches the data from the actual init.

Comment: maybe because you are using `self` (by executing one of its methods) when all of its properties have not been initialized
try to initialize userWallets (with an empty array) before executing the method